# Entity Framework / MVC: Writing a collection to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

What I have looks something like this:

```
class foo
{
  [Key]
  int ID;
  List<Bar> bars;
  string s;
}
class bar
{
  [Key]
  int ID;
  string s;
}
```

then in the controller:

```
public ActionResult BeAwesome(foo doo)
{
  db.Entry(doo).State = EntityState.Modified;
  db.SaveChanges();
  return View(doo);
}
```

I can confirm that doo is being passed in with a list of bars, but the bars are not being propagated to the database.  doo.s does get saved.  What do I need to do to get the collection to save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define the properties like this,

```
public virtual  List<Bar> bars{get; set;}
```

and also you need to define navigational properties as virtual to enable lazy-loading.

Comment: Doing this and setting the bars to modified took care of it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried attaching the entity to the context before you set its state?

```
db.foos.attach(doo);
db.Entry(doo).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

What happens if you set the state of each bar in the doo to EntityState.Modified?  Or possibly attaching each of the bars individually in a loop.

Comment: +1 If the objects aren't attached - e.g. they've come back from a View - they won't persist.

Comment: In DbContext API setting state to Modified attach the object automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that only foo is set to `Modified` - all related bars are in `Unchanged` state. You must iterate through bars and set their state as well:

```
public ActionResult BeAwesome(foo doo)
{
  db.Entry(doo).State = EntityState.Modified;
  foo.Bars.ForEach(b => db.Entry(b).State = EntityState.Modified);
  db.SaveChanges();
  return View(doo);
}
```

Obviously if you have some bars inserted or deleted you need more complex logic to set the state.